# Why does my program accept one integer too many and input one too few?

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

I'd like to understand why the program allows me to input 3 integers when I have defined SIZE as 2. And when it returns the array it only returns two numbers NOT the three I have entered.Thanks for your help.

```
//C How to Program Exercises 2.23
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define SIZE 2

int main (void){

    int myArray[SIZE];
    int count;
    printf("Please enter 5 integers\n");
    for (count=1;count<=SIZE;count++){
        scanf("%d\n",&myArray[count]);
    }
    for (count=1;count<=SIZE;count++){
        printf("The values of myArray are %d\n",myArray[count]);
    }
    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C arrays are zero-based, that's a first serious issue with your code! Your size 2 array has elements 0 and 1, so in your case already the second element entered will end up outside of the array. Correct that first.

Comment: I understand what you said about the array. do you know the program lets me input more than 2 elements?

Comment: @RaphaelJones That's because of the `\n` you have. Because of that scanf() call will only complete if you input a non-whitespace character.

Comment: @BlueMoon, yes, if multiple numbers are entered on the same line.  If the extra number is read when each is entered on its own line, then a different explanation is needed.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The explanation is still the same. Subsequent call to scanf accepts the previously inputted number. So it'll require one extra input for the last scanf() call to finish.

Comment: @BlueMoon, you're right.  I was not paying attention to the newline in the format string.  It bears repeating (what you wrote in your answer) that the meaning of that newline to `scanf()` is quite different than the OP probably thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loops should be

```
for (count=0;count<SIZE;count++)
```

Array indexing is `0` based in C.

Since you have a whitespace chatacter (`\n`) in `scanf()` call, it waits for you input a non-whitespace character to complete each call. Remove the `\n`:

```
   for (count=0;count<SIZE;count++){
    scanf("%d",&myArray[count]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C arrays are indexed starting from `0`, not from `1`.  C does not automatically perform bounds checking on array accesses, and indeed, your code is well-formed.  However, its runtime behavior is *undefined* on account of its using an array element expression to write outside the bounds of that array, and, separately, on account of its using an array element expression to read outside the bounds of that array.

Inasmuchas the program definitely exhibits undefined behavior on every run, absolutely nothing can be said about what it should do.  If in practice you observe the input loop iterating thrice, then a likely explanation is that the second iteration overwrites the value of the `count` variable.  Given the order in which the variables are declared, this is a plausible manifestation of the undefined behavior in play.

The output loop, on the other hand, iterates exactly the number of times you told it to do: once with `count == 1`, and once more with `count == 2`.  This is by no means guaranteed given the general undefinedness of an execution of your program, but it is about the *least surprising* behavior I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

> why the program allows me to input 3 integers

This loop runs exactly 2 times:

```
for (count=1;count<=SIZE;count++){
        scanf("%d\n",&myArray[count]);
    }
```

But as you used `\n` in the `scanf()`, this `scanf()` waits until you give any whitespace.

`Proper Input code:`

```
for (count=0;count<SIZE;count++){
        scanf("%d",&myArray[count]);
    }
```

> And when it returns the array it only returns two numbers

Your original output code prints first number correctly, But your second number is garbage value.

`Proper Output Code:`

```
for (count=0;count<SIZE;count++){
        printf("The values of myArray are %d\n",myArray[count]);
    }
```

So Full Code goes like this:

```
//C How to Program Exercises 2.23
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define SIZE 2

int main (void){

    int myArray[SIZE];
    int count;
    printf("Please enter 5 integers\n");
    for (count=0;count<SIZE;count++){
        scanf("%d",&myArray[count]);
    }
    for (count=0;count<SIZE;count++){
        printf("The values of myArray are %d\n",myArray[count]);
    }
    getch();

    return 0;
}
```